# SoapUI/Maven/Bamboo: Exceptions in Bamboo job

Tags: maven, soapui, bamboo

I have an xml with soapui autotests. I done POM for building with maven. It is successfully works from cmd.

But now I need to add this to Bamboo.

I successfully created job, which is "look" at correct place of project in repo, but exceptions in logs:

1)

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSException
    build   05-Feb-2015 15:37:41        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.RequestTransportRegistry.<clinit>(RequestTransportRegistry.java:47)
    build   05-Feb-2015 15:37:41        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.http.HttpRequest.submit(HttpRequest.java:278)

...

    build   05-Feb-2015 15:37:41        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    build   05-Feb-2015 15:37:41        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    build   05-Feb-2015 15:37:41        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    build   05-Feb-2015 15:37:41        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    build   05-Feb-2015 15:37:41        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    build   05-Feb-2015 15:37:41    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.JMSException
    build   05-Feb-2015 15:37:41        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
```

I added jms dependency, but it did not help:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

and 2nd exception:

2)

```
build   05-Feb-2015 15:37:41    15:37:41,840 ERROR [AbstractTestRunner] Exception during Test Execution
build   05-Feb-2015 15:37:41    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.RequestTransportRegistry
build   05-Feb-2015 15:37:41        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.http.HttpRequest.submit(HttpRequest.java:278)
build   05-Feb-2015 15:37:41        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.HttpTestRequestStep.run(HttpTestRequestStep.java:306)
```

So, this is a problem:)...

Suggestion: may be problem is in following part of log of bamboo job:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project soapui-maven2-plugin: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.smartbear.samples:soapui-maven2-plugin:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1 in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) ->
```

pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.smartbear.samples</groupId>
    <artifactId>soapui-maven3-plugin</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Maven 3 SoapUI Sample</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.jboss.org-public</id>
            <name>JBoss.org Maven repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>smartbear-sweden-plugin-repository</id>
            <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
                <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>1st project </id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectFile>${project.basedir}/test-project.xml</projectFile>
                            <outputFolder>${project.basedir}/target/surefire-reports</outputFolder>
                            <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>2nd project </id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectFile>${project.basedir}/Search_Live.xml</projectFile>
                            <outputFolder>${project.basedir}/target/surefire-reports</outputFolder>
                            <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

</project>
```

stacktrace of bamboo job.

```
    simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:41    Build Auto Tests Soap UI - SmokeTesting - Default Job #25 (ATSU-SMOK-JOB1-25) started building on agent Agent#3
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:41    Build working directory is /opt/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/63897602/ATSU-SMOK-JOB1
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:41    Executing build Auto Tests Soap UI - SmokeTesting - Default Job #25 (ATSU-SMOK-JOB1-25)
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:41    Starting task 'Checkout Default Repository' of type 'com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.vcs:task.vcs.checkout'
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:41    Updating source code to revision: 3e72a932c057d15fb38c72ed256db1cf4610e9de
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:41    Fetching 'refs/heads/master' from 'https://bitbucket.org/mikiebiz/soapui'.
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:42    Checking out revision 3e72a932c057d15fb38c72ed256db1cf4610e9de.
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:42    Note: checking out '3e72a932c057d15fb38c72ed256db1cf4610e9de'.
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:42    
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:42    You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:42    changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:42    state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:42    
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:42    If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:42    do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:42    
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:42      git checkout -b new_branch_name
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:42    
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:42    HEAD is now at 3e72a93... pom change 4
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:42    Updated source code to revision: 3e72a932c057d15fb38c72ed256db1cf4610e9de
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:42    Finished task 'Checkout Default Repository'
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:42    Running pre-build action: Clover Grails PreBuild Action
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:42    Running pre-build action: VCS Version Collector
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:42    Running pre-build action: Artifactory Release Staging
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:42    Starting task 'test soap proj' of type 'com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.maven:task.builder.mvn3'
command 06-Feb-2015 09:06:42    Beginning to execute external process for build 'Auto Tests Soap UI - SmokeTesting - Default Job #25 (ATSU-SMOK-JOB1-25)'\n ... running command line: \n/opt/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin/mvn --batch-mode -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/bamboo-5/temp/ATSU-SMOK-JOB1 clean site\n ... in: /opt/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/63897602/ATSU-SMOK-JOB1/maven soapui\n ... using extra environment variables: \nbamboo_was_stg_password=********\nbamboo_was_swan_test_port=8879\nJAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest\nuseMavenReturnCode=false\nbamboo_was_test_user=wasadmin\nbamboo_live_artefact_repo=/opt/bamboo_live_artefacts\nM2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.0.5\nbamboo_sprint_number=14.16\nbamboo_was_swan_test_password=********\nbamboo_was_test_port=8879\nMAVEN2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.0.5\nbamboo_was_test_host=10.100.1.45\nbamboo_was_stg_port=18879\nbamboo_WAS7_HOME=/opt/IBM/WebSphere7/AppServer\nbamboo_SWAN_WAS7_HOME=/opt/IBM/WebSphere8.5.5/AppServer\nbamboo_was_stg_user=wasadmin\nbamboo_was_test_password=********\nbamboo_was_stg_host=10.100.1.134\nbamboo_was_swan_test_host=10.100.1.16\nbamboo_was_swan_test_user=wasadmin\nPATH=/usr/java/latest/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/bin:/bin\n
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:44    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:44    [INFO]                                                                         
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:44    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:44    [INFO] Building Maven 3 SoapUI Sample 1.0-SNAPSHOT
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:44    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:45    [INFO] 
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:45    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ soapui-maven3-plugin ---
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:45    [INFO] Deleting /opt/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/63897602/ATSU-SMOK-JOB1/maven soapui/target
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:45    [INFO] 
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:45    [INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.3:site (default-site) @ soapui-maven3-plugin ---
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:46    [INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-report-plugin:2.7.2
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:47    [INFO] 
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:47    [INFO] >>> maven-surefire-report-plugin:2.7.2:report (report:report) @ soapui-maven3-plugin >>>
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:47    [INFO] 
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:47    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ soapui-maven3-plugin ---
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:47    [debug] execute contextualize
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:47    [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:47    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /opt/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/63897602/ATSU-SMOK-JOB1/maven soapui/src/main/resources
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:47    [INFO] 
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:47    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ soapui-maven3-plugin ---
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:47    [INFO] No sources to compile
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:47    [INFO] 
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:47    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ soapui-maven3-plugin ---
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:47    [debug] execute contextualize
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:47    [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:47    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /opt/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/63897602/ATSU-SMOK-JOB1/maven soapui/src/test/resources
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:47    [INFO] 
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:47    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ soapui-maven3-plugin ---
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:47    [INFO] No sources to compile
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:47    [INFO] 
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:47    [INFO] --- soapui-maven-plugin:5.0.0:test (1st project) @ soapui-maven3-plugin ---
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:48    SoapUI 5.0.0 Maven2 TestCase Runner
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:48    09:06:48,707 WARN  [SoapUI] Missing folder [/opt/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/63897602/ATSU-SMOK-JOB1/maven soapui/ext] for external libraries
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:48    09:06:48,708 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] Creating new settings at [/home/bamboo/soapui-settings.xml]
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:50    09:06:50,205 INFO  [WsdlProject] Loaded project from [file:/opt/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/63897602/ATSU-SMOK-JOB1/maven%20soapui/test-project.xml]
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:51    09:06:51,128 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Running SoapUI tests in project [test proj for maven]
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:51    09:06:51,130 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Running Project [test proj for maven], runType = SEQUENTIAL
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:51    09:06:51,150 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Running SoapUI testcase [5.0 Search_Accor_ADG002_STAGING]
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:51    09:06:51,184 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] running step [Properties]
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:51    09:06:51,265 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] running step [Given Dates]
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    09:06:52,051 INFO  [log]  Service Date:  Fri Feb 20 09:06:51 GMT 2015
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    09:06:52,052 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] running step [When Search by given conditions]
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    09:06:52,071 ERROR [AbstractTestRunner] Exception during Test Execution
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSException
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.RequestTransportRegistry.<clinit>(RequestTransportRegistry.java:47)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.http.HttpRequest.submit(HttpRequest.java:278)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.HttpTestRequestStep.run(HttpTestRequestStep.java:306)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.runTestStep(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:239)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.runCurrentTestStep(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:52)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:152)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:47)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.run(AbstractTestRunner.java:139)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.JMSException
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        ... 13 more
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    09:06:52,073 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Finished running SoapUI testcase [5.0 Search_Accor_ADG002_STAGING], time taken: 858ms, status: FAILED
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    09:06:52,080 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Running SoapUI testcase [5.2 Search_Accor_ADG002_two rooms_STAGING]
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    09:06:52,081 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] running step [Properties]
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    09:06:52,081 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] running step [Given Dates]
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    09:06:52,172 INFO  [log]  Service Date:  Fri Feb 20 09:06:52 GMT 2015
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    09:06:52,172 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] running step [When Search by given conditions]
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    09:06:52,173 ERROR [AbstractTestRunner] Exception during Test Execution
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.RequestTransportRegistry
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.http.HttpRequest.submit(HttpRequest.java:278)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.HttpTestRequestStep.run(HttpTestRequestStep.java:306)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.runTestStep(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:239)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.runCurrentTestStep(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:52)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:152)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:47)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.run(AbstractTestRunner.java:139)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    09:06:52,173 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Finished running SoapUI testcase [5.2 Search_Accor_ADG002_two rooms_STAGING], time taken: 90ms, status: FAILED
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    09:06:52,175 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Running SoapUI testcase [5.0 Search_Best Western_ADG013_STAGING]
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    09:06:52,175 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] running step [Properties]
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    09:06:52,175 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] running step [Given Dates]
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    09:06:52,256 INFO  [log]  Service Date:  Fri Feb 20 09:06:52 GMT 2015
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    09:06:52,256 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] running step [When Search by given conditions]
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    09:06:52,257 ERROR [AbstractTestRunner] Exception during Test Execution
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.RequestTransportRegistry
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.http.HttpRequest.submit(HttpRequest.java:278)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.HttpTestRequestStep.run(HttpTestRequestStep.java:306)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.runTestStep(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:239)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.runCurrentTestStep(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:52)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:152)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:47)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.run(AbstractTestRunner.java:139)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    09:06:52,257 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Finished running SoapUI testcase [5.0 Search_Best Western_ADG013_STAGING], time taken: 80ms, status: FAILED
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    09:06:52,259 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Project [test proj for maven] finished with status [FAILED] in 1122ms
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    [ERROR] java.lang.Exception: TestCase [5.0 Search_Accor_ADG002_STAGING] failed without assertions
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    TestCase [5.2 Search_Accor_ADG002_two rooms_STAGING] failed without assertions
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    TestCase [5.0 Search_Best Western_ADG013_STAGING] failed without assertions
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    [INFO] Total time: 7.699s
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    [INFO] Finished at: Fri Feb 06 09:06:52 GMT 2015
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    [INFO] Final Memory: 32M/360M
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site (default-site) on project soapui-maven3-plugin: failed to get report for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-report-plugin: Failed to execute goal com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:5.0.0:test (1st project) on project soapui-maven3-plugin: SoapUI Test(s) failed: SoapUI Test(s) failed:
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    [ERROR] TestCase [5.0 Search_Accor_ADG002_STAGING] failed without assertions
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    [ERROR] TestCase [5.2 Search_Accor_ADG002_two rooms_STAGING] failed without assertions
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    [ERROR] TestCase [5.0 Search_Best Western_ADG013_STAGING] failed without assertions
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    [ERROR] 
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    [ERROR] 
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
build   06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    Failing task since return code of [/opt/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin/mvn --batch-mode -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/bamboo-5/temp/ATSU-SMOK-JOB1 clean site] was 1 while expected 0
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    Parsing test results...
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    Finished task 'test soap proj'
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    Running post build plugin 'NCover Results Collector'
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    Running post build plugin 'Clover Results Collector'
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    Running post build plugin 'Artifact Copier'
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    Running post build plugin 'Artifactory Release Management Staging'
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    Running post build plugin 'Artifactory Build Info Copier'
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    Running post build plugin 'Artifactory Gradle Properties Info Copier'
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    Finalising the build...
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    Stopping timer.
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    Build ATSU-SMOK-JOB1-25 completed.
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    Running on server: post build plugin 'NCover Results Collector'
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    Running on server: post build plugin 'Clover Delta Calculator'
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    Running on server: post build plugin 'Sonar Build Password Processor'
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    Running on server: post build plugin 'Build Hanging Detection Configuration'
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    Running on server: post build plugin 'Maven Dependencies Postprocessor'
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    All post build plugins have finished
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:52    Generating build results summary...
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:53    Saving build results to disk...
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:53    Indexing build results...
simple  06-Feb-2015 09:06:53    Finished building ATSU-SMOK-JOB1-25.
```

Comment: Can you show more of your pom?

Comment: sure. will be added to question body in a minute.

Comment: What is http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven3/ in the pluginRepository? That URL does not exist; it should be "maven2".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hooray, seems I solved the problem. I just changed dependency for jms from

```
   <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

to jeronimo

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
    <artifactId>geronimo-jms_1.1_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

and all is ok now.

Answer (score 0):

You have things in wrong order. The following should work:

First change the pluginRepository URL from maven**3** to maven**2**! Then change your plugin definitions to this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
    <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>1st project </id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <projectFile>${project.basedir}/test-project.xml</projectFile>
                <outputFolder>${project.basedir}/target/surefire-reports</outputFolder>
                <junitReport>true</junitReport>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>2nd project </id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <projectFile>${project.basedir}/Search_Live.xml</projectFile>
                <outputFolder>${project.basedir}/target/surefire-reports</outputFolder>
                <junitReport>true</junitReport>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

You can get additional details in the [official documentation](http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x.html).

Comment: Thanks for Your help, SiKing. Unfortunately,  errors still the same:(. Actually, Official documentation u gave link - was used for POM building by me. that maven 3 is just "dances"...  I changed POM in question body for that, which is now, and returns same errors in Bamboo(from cmd all works fine...)...

Comment: I added full stacktrace of Bamboo job also.